# Determine the map's load status in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QT project including a QML map which loads a plugin such as Google-map. I want to know  is there a way to check QML Map rendering/loading status without a third party library?

`Component.onCompleted` gets triggered only for the first time the Map element is loaded. On subsequent operations with the map, like dragging, the map loads in tiles but I can't find any way to know when the map is completely drawn.

I know that using `Esri.ArcGISRuntime` in my project as a third party library leads to arise the event `onLoadStatusChanged` including load status, like `Enums.LoadStatusFailedToLoad`, `Enums.LoadStatusLoaded`,  `Enums.LoadStatusLoading`; But is there a similar event in builtin QML-Qt?

Comment: Use `mapReady` property https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#mapReady-prop: `onMapReady: console.log(mapReady)`

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, but there is just `onMapReadyChanged` in map which does not work as desired!

Comment: From what I understand you want to get the errors that can occur when loading tiles (and other types of errors) then use the error property: `onErrorChanged: console.log(error, errorString)`

Comment: `onMapReadyChanged` is emitted only after the `Map` is initialized, not after each loading/change. There is no signal to do what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to know when loading the map tiles is finished and after loading the map, I want to call some procedures.

Comment: No it can not be done. Qt does not offer that feature